# gdb Program exited code 01 for program using CMake

Tags: c++, linux, qt, emacs, gdb

I am using scientific linux. I am dealing with a huge amount of code in C++ with tons of cpp files. Right now, it compiles successfully, but the values/data I'm getting are definitely wrong. Also, for some small changes I make to the code causes seg faults.

In the directory `user/project/Build`, I enter `make` to compile and link all the cpp files. I then have to go to `user/project/Build/bin/project` to run the project binary by typing `user/run/run.sh`

When I go to directory `/user/project/Build/bin` and then type `gdb project` and then `run`, I see 
`Program exited with code 01. Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc..`

If I try to set a breakpoint, such as by `break test.cpp:19`, I get the message `No source file named test.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?`
But I clearly have a source file named test.cpp

How can I set breakpoints? Considering that I'm a beginner with Unix, should I use another IDE such as emacs or Qt creator?

Comment: To set breakpoints by line number, you need to pass the `-g` option to the C++ compiler. Here's a question/answer that says how to do that for typical cases: [Compiling with cmake and include debug information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8447957/2554472)

Comment: In my `Build` directory, I entered `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug ../src`. But the output I got was `Looking for pthread_create - not found.
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at log4cplus/CMakeLists.txt:152 (SetupBoost):
  Unknown CMake command "SetupBoost".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

Comment: OK. So you normally run `cmake ../src` and that works?

Comment: What do you mean? I just entered that because that is what they suggested on that link you provided. To compile, I just enter `make`

Comment: OK, so you're using CMake, but you never had to use the `cmake` command?

Comment: Let's just look at the files that `make uses. If you have a file named `Makefile` or `makefile`, is there a line in it that starts with `CFLAGS=` ?

Comment: In the `Makefile`, there is no line with `CFLAGS`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you're using C++, not C.  Is there a `CXXFLAGS` line? If not, please add a line near the top of the Makefile that says `CXXFLAGS+= -g`, then recompile. The g++ or clang++ command lines that `make` spews should have a `-g` in them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the MakeFile says at the top `CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!`. Can I just ignore that? Or is there a way to add that CXXFLAGS via the prompt?

Comment: Edit Makefile for now. Worst that can happen is that the manual changes you make to Makefile get overwritten by cmake at some point. Ultimately, we will need to know what command in the `cmake` family of commands you type to generate that Makefile.

Comment: ok, I edited the Makefile to include the CXXFLAGS but now the error is `/opt/apps/ossw/applications/cmake/cmake-2.8.9/sl6/gcc-4.6/bin/cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found (required by /opt/apps/ossw/applications/cmake/cmake-2.8.9/sl6/gcc-4.6/bin/cmake)`

Comment: Odd. If you remove that new `CXXFLAGS` line from Makefile, the error goes away?

Comment: turns out that I think I got that error because I forgot to type `module load boost`. Once I did that, I was able to compile successfully even with that `CXXFLAGS` line in the MakeFile. But when I try to run gdb again, I get the same messages as in the OP

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find a solution. Someone else will help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the huge amount of code you are struggling with?

Comment: And how big is that code? Do you have more experienced colleagues working on it (you probably do, if the code is huge as you say it is)

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) of GDB? It is definitely worthwhile to read it. Read also some [tutorial](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html) on `gdb`

If your `Makefile`-s are generated by *cmake*, you should also study the [documentation of `cmake`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/) and the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) of `make`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205917/841108) to a related question.

Did you compile *all* your software with `g++ -Wall -g` (and *without* any optimization flags like `-O1` or `-O2`) - or perhaps even `-g3` instead of `-g`?

You might even install debugging variants of the major libraries you are using (e.g. packages like `glibc-debuginfo` etc...)

You probably want to specify (for `gdb`) the source directories to search with the [`dir` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) of `gdb` ...

And yes, I recommend using `emacs`. But above all, I strongly recommend spending hours (and perhaps days or even weeks) to learn more about Linux and software development on it (there are lots of books, websites, [tutorials](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Scientific-Computing-with-GNU-Linux/) and [other](http://www.bu.edu/tech/about/training/classroom/rcs-tutorials/) training, ... about that). Maybe start with a small, hello-world like, program (learning how to compile it with `g++` and to debug it with `gdb`). Then try to compile and debug a small (e.g. of a hundred thousand lines of source code) free software that you like (e.g. [fishshell](http://fishshell.com/) or anything you've got from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net) or [github](http://github.com/)), just to get a feeling of how such software is built.

If you are using (or improving) a big scientific software, it probably has some community website, mailing list, or forum for help (see [geant](https://geant4.web.cern.ch/geant4/) or [kiva](http://www.lanl.gov/orgs/t/t3/codes/kiva.shtml) or [aster](http://www.code-aster.org) as examples, which I only know by name!). Please also use them.

<sup>PS. It is not mostly a matter of choosing tools: you are using the good ones (GCC i.e. `g++`, `emacs`, `gdb`, `make`, `grep` or [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), [etags](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/etags.html), [git](http://git-scm.com/), `awk`, ....). It is a matter to get the knowledge -spending weeks or months of your time- about how to use them wisely and combine their use. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28651503/841108).</sup>

Comment: If it a code on which only a dozen people worked it is not a *huge* code, but a middle-sized one. the GCC compiler, the Linux kernel, the mozilla browser, or the GEANT4 simulation code have many millions lines of code (so are developed by several hundred people each). And if there is no community around that code, you should start one!

Comment: Adn you really should edit your questions to improve them by explaining more, and give more context. At least explain in a few sentences what your code is doing, how it is organized (whatr size is it) etc.