# Importing C++ project to Eclipse - overlaps workspace

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, unix, makefile

I have a project that I generated using make and C++ files using Unix. I want to import it to Eclipse, but get the message:

`/workspace/Arthur/cmake/nuclear overlaps the workspace location: /workspace/Arthur/cmake/nuclear`

Even when I try to set the location to `/workspace/Arthur/cmake/`, `/workspace/Arthur`, `/workspace/`, I get the same message that the location overlaps with `/workspace/Arthur/cmake/nuclear`

What should I do?

Comment: Keep using `make` on the command line. If you have to use Eclipse, use it only as an editor.

Comment: But my code is huge, I'm having trouble getting gdb to debug and it's been taking me almost a month just to deal with the bugs in my code. Should I just try Qt creator or Kdevelop instead?

Comment: How big is your code (how many millions lines of source code)? What does it do? Please edit your question to tell that! Why are you switching to Eclipse? Are you already familiar with Eclipse (e.g. using it for Java projects)?

Comment: I would suggest you to use `emacs` (or `vim` if you know it and prefer it). And you should explain what are the troubles you have with `gdb` (which is the debugger that Eclipse is using)

Comment: I explained the problem with gdb here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680739/gdb-program-exited-code-01-for-program-using-cmake?noredirect=1#comment45692466_28680739

Comment: I added some answer to that other question. But I believe you should edit your question to improve it, and tell much more about the software you are struggling with. You cannot get good help with such vague and broad questions!

Comment: Also, if the community working on that huge code is usually not using Eclipse (but e.g. uses emacs) stay with the tools that are usually used by the community using on, and working on, your huge code. And ask the community around the huge code you are using!

Answer (score 0):

An eclipse workspace for an existing project should not be in the same location as the code.  The eclipse workspace directory will contain information that eclipse needs to manage your workspace, not necessarily the source code.  The solution is to create the workspace in an empty location. Then import the project using File->Import->Existing Code as Makefile Project.  Once you import the project, right click on the project in the Project Explorer and go to properties->C/C++Build and update the 'Build Location' to be the folder that you normally use to make the project.

Comment: For File->Import->Existing Code as Makefile Projec, what am I supposed to choose for the Existing Code Location? I tried to select `/workspace/Arthur/cmake/nuclear` but it won't let me go to the next step

Comment: The 'Next>' button is grayed out because there are no additional steps.  At this point, you just click 'Finish'

Comment: When I try to click 'Finish', nothing happens. It won't let me click on Finish