# gdb will not run and hit breakpoints

Tags: c++, debugging, unix

I am using unix with a project that deals with C++ source files.

In the directory`user/project/Build`, I enter `make` to compile and link the source files and then go to `user/run` and enter `run.sh test.txt` to run the program

After I go to `/user/project/Build/bin` and enter `gdb project` and then `run`, I always get the message `Program exited with code 01. Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc.`

Although I can set breakpoints in `main.cpp`, if I enter 'break foo.cpp:19', I see `No source file named foo.cpp. Make breakpoint pending on future shared 
library load?` But this is wrong because I have `foo.cpp`

When I head to Build and try `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
../src`, I receive `looking for pthread_create - not found. --
Found Threads: TRUE CMake Error at`
`log4cplus/CMakeLists.txt:152
(SetupBoost): Unknown CMake command "SetupBoost".`
`-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`. The problem does not get resolved even
if I edit the Makefile to include the CXXFLAGS

What is going on?

Comment: Did you search "Missing separate debuginfos"?  Seems like there's a lot of answers as to why you might be having issues.

Comment: There is already [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28706984/841108) to a very similar question of yours. You need to give appropriate `dir` commands to `gdb` to overcome the "No source file named foo.cpp" error!